# How to configure your git daemon to allow only read only permissions for one repository on gitlab

Tags: git, configuration, daemon

I'm trying to configure a git daemon service that allows to pull from a specific gitlab repository (connected via ssh), but not any other repositories or git pull statements.

We are hosting a server on which multiple users have access. My gitlab account is connected through ssh to the server. However, the allows the user on the server to access by gitlab account. Therefore, I want to change the server users permissions to read only the specific gitlab repository. From our local machines, we will be able to push, but on the server only pull permissions are necessary.

I followed the documentation provided on https://git-scm.com/docs/git-daemon/1.7.0 and https://git-scm.com/book/nl/v2/Git-op-de-server-Git-Daemon but I can still pull the repository without the need to add a git-daemon-export-ok file, and I can still push to the repository from the server user.

I have not set the export-all argument somewhere, and I also tried to enter this code

```
[daemon]
    upload-pack=true
    upload-archive=false
    receive-pack=false
```

to the config files. But this still throws no 'permission denied' errors